# MongoDB C# UpdateBuilder not ignoring nulls on set

Tags: c#, mongodb, reflection

I have the following two classes where a user sets preferences. The user may not have any preferences, only likes, only dislikes, or both. I slimmed down the User model for simplicity in this example.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class User : Base
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public UserPreferences Preferences { get; set; }
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class UserPreferences
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<string> Likes { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public List<string> Dislikes { get; set; }
}
```

I have a helper function which uses reflection to construct an UpdateBuilder. When given a user object it sets a value for non-null fields since I don't want to specifically write out which fields have been updated on a call. However the helper function fails in my current situation.

```
    public override User Update(User model)
    {

        var builder = Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.Id, model.Id);

        foreach(PropertyInfo prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(model, null);

            if ((prop.Name != "Id") & (value != null))
            {
                builder = builder.Set(prop.Name, value);
            }
        }

        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter;
        var filter_def = filter.Eq(x => x.Id, model.Id);

        Connection.Update(filter_def, builder);

        return model;

    }
```

**Problem:** When supplying `Preferences` with only `Likes` or only `Dislikes`, it will make the other property null in MongoDB.

**Desired Result:** I want MongoDB to ignore either the `Likes` or `Dislikes` property if the list is null like it does for other properties in my code.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? In "reality" the document should create in the database with "both" properties set to an empty array. When you actually "modify" then you would only address the specific property you actually want to update. Be that A. The specific matched element of the desired array to "change" the value. B. To push the "new element" into the specified array. If you are writing a `Set` which is essentially overwriting each property with the "whole" array content in your class instance, then you are doing it "wrong"!

Comment: I understand what you're saying. In this case, not everyone has Preferences from the beginning, so some users do not have the field. On update, any number of tags could be added for likes & dislikes on the application UI. User could have likes: [a,b,c,d,e,f] and change it to likes: [b,c,g,h,i]. Hence, the array is just set. Dislikes are set on another screen where likes may not be present.

Comment: In your foreach you are only looking one level deep.  Since preferences is not null it will overwrite both values within preferences.  It will only ignore the set if preferences is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to unset the field if its value is null

```
public override User Update(User model)
{

    var builder = Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.Id, model.Id);

    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(model, null);

        if (prop.Name != "Id")
        {
           if(value != null)
           {
                builder = builder.Set(prop.Name, value);
           }
           else
           {
                builder = builder.Unset(prop.Name);
           }
            
        }
    }

    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter;
    var filter_def = filter.Eq(x => x.Id, model.Id);

    Connection.Update(filter_def, builder);

    return model;

}
```

I hope this will solve your issue